# How to get email address of all users in Django

Tags: django, django-users, django-email

I am learning django and I am stuck with this problem.

How do I get the email address of all the users in Django. The user can be of any type like superuser, general user etc.

I tried the following but I am not getting email address of all the users.

```
user = User.objects.get(id=2)
user_email = user. Email
print(user_email)
```

I want something like a list of all the email addresses. Can someone please help me with it?

Comment: Do you need a list of all the emails?

Comment: @lucutzu33 Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
email_list = list(User.objects.values_list("email", flat=True))
```

Read more about `values_list` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list